# How to change content of fragment in pagerview

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a Page which has three buttons (teens, adult, old) and same page contains view pager which has 7 tabs for week days. When this page loaded it show list of all programs for all (teens, adult and old) categories in all 7 tabs according to which day is. What I want to implement is that when user select anyone one of the above button the contents of all the tabs populated by new filtered data list according to the selected button.
How I can implement this?.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the selection in your Adapter and then call notifyDataChanged. That will reload the adapter and go back through the instantiateItem calls again. In instantiateItem you can look at the selection and change the content accordingly.